# Forbidden, when accessing public dir with Apache 2.2.22 + Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, forbidden

I need make `/var/html/tomcat/public_www/` accessible from public, but I can't figure out why I still getting *Forbidden* error page. The permission of this folder are set to 777 & the folder has the same over:group as Apache process.

In the Apache log is:

```
 [Mon Sep 07 13:44:57 2015] [crit] [client 12.10.180.135] (13)Permission denied: /var/html/tomcat/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

**site-enabled/example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

    <Virtualhost *:80>

        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteOptions Inherit
        Options FollowSymlinks

        JkMount /* ajp13_worker
        JkUnMount /error/* ajp13_worker
        JkUnMount /static/* ajp13_worker

        DocumentRoot /var/html/tomcat/public_www/

        ErrorLog /var/html/tomcat/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/html/tomcat/logs/access.log common

        <Directory /var/html/tomcat/public_www/>
                Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorDocument 503 /error/503/index.html
        ErrorDocument 404 /error/404/index.html
    </Virtualhost>
```

My `httpd.conf` file is empty. Could you please tell me what wrong is with my config? I also do not understand why is the Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) queering `/var/html/tomcat/.htaccess` file even though the `AllowOverride none` option was set to none.

Thanks

Comment: Check your `htaccess file` file permission. Probably Apache cant read the file.

Comment: I tried create the file `/var/html/tomcat/.htaccess` set permissions to `777` but still the same. But I do not want have the file at given path. I do not need this .htacess file. I need only make `/var/html/tomcat/public_www` and contained contend reachable from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved this issue. The reason why it was not working was that on `tomcat` folder were wrong permissions.